# Will UVC light/ozone affects color on fabrics?

Tags: color, ozone

I'm planning to put a low power UVC light bulb into my wardrobe to kill bacteria and prevent bad smell on clothes but I'm wondering will it affect color on the clothes? I've done some research but haven't got into a conclusion if UVC light will affect color faster than sunlight or not (because there's no UVC light reaches the earth surface).

I have 2 light bulbs, 1 able to produce ozone and the other doesn't, ozone can help reaching the dead spots which UV rays can't reach but I've read that ozone will cause cracking on some plastic do fabrics also get affected by that?

Comment: Ozone will attack any fabric. UV light tends to bleach dyes. All in all this is a very bad idea.

Comment: Ozone destroys bugs using exactly sort of chemical reactions that will destroy fabrics and bleach dyes. All UV light will cause some bleaching of dyes and other damage to fabrics. You will destroy your clothes faster than cleaning them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm planning to put a low power UVC light bulb into my wardrobe to **kill bacteria** and prevent bad smell on clothes but I'm wondering will it affect color on the clothes?

If the UV light is strong enough to break bonds to kill bacteria it is certainly strong enough to bleach the organic dyes and degrade the clothing.

> I've done some research but haven't got into a conclusion if UVC light will affect color **faster than sunlight** or not (because there's no UVC light reaches the earth surface).

This depends on the brightness of the bulb and the sun where you live

> ...but I've read that ozone will cause cracking on some plastic do fabrics also get affected by that?

Yes fabrics are also degraded by ozone.

Keep in mind that though the UV and ozone may cause degradation of your clothes, they may or may not do so faster than mold or normal use would too many factors to say with certainty which is best.